# jQuery + XML: Parsing node parent

Tags: jquery, xml

I have this XML:

```
<node-type-A>
    <node-type-B name='somname1'>
        <mynode>mynodevalue-1</mynode>
    </node-type-B>
    <node-type-B name='somname2'>
        <mynode>mynodevalue-2</mynode>
    </node-type-B>
</node-type-A>

<node-type-A>
    <node-type-B name='somname3'>
        <mynode>mynodevalue-3</mynode>
    </node-type-B>
</node-type-A>
```

Now, I have mynode value (This is input). I need to output the name of node-type-B IF the super-parent node-type-A has more than one node-type-B.

- So if the input is mynodevalue-2 then it will output somname2.
- If the input is mynodevalue-3 then it will not output anything, since its super parent node-type-A has only one node-type-B.
- If the input is mynodevalue-1 then it will output somname1 (since its super parent node-type-A has multiple node-type-B).

I am using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` method:

```
$('node-type-A').filter(function(){
    return $('node-type-B', this).length > 1
}).find('node-type-B').each(function(){
    console.log(this.name)
})
```